# Hide scrollbars of a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I'm trying to write a simple text editor like DarkRoom with just a RichTextBox (or alternatively a TextBox) in it. My problem is that I can't use the mouse wheel for scrolling unless I have a vertical scrollbar. Is there any way to hide this scrollbar and still be able to scroll with the mouse wheel?

So far I have several ideas how this could be done, but no idea how to implement them.

- re-create the scrolling code using a MouseWheel event
- change the visual style of the scrollbar to hide it or make it less visible
- write my own TextBox widget
- overlap the scrollbars with something else to hide them

P.S.: Using any win32 stuff is not an option.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you will have to capture the .MouseWheel and .MouseMove events. See [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/8e83865a-0cb9-4e7a-94db-356d542e5680/).

Ok, do something like following:

1. Add a line in form load event.

   ```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       this.richTextBox1.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(richTextBox1_MouseWheel);
   }
   ```
2. Add following in mouse wheel event.

   ```
   void richTextBox1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Delta > 0)
       {
           //Handle mouse move upwards
           if (richTextBox1.SelectionStart > 10)
           {
               richTextBox1.SelectionStart -= 10;
               richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
           }
       }
       else
       {
           //Mouse move downwards.
           richTextBox1.SelectionStart += 10;
           richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
       }
   }
   ```

Let me know in either cases, if you would want the running sample of the same; or if you are not liking the solution (0:

Comment: That doesn't explain how to do the scrolling part. That's were I'm stuck right now.

Comment: That's not exactly the right scrolling behavior I was looking for. The caret position shouldn't change while scrolling. But even if I set the SelectionStart back to the original value I won't get the right behavior. It might work if I know at which character position the visible line at the top starts or the line at the bottom ends. Just increasing/decreasing the SelectionStart value by a constant number doesn't work however.
While testing this I also noticed that ScrollToCaret will scroll up and down a few pixels if the caret is already visible.

Comment: Thanks Maurice for your feedback. Actually, according to your question 'Is there any way to hide this scrollbar and still be able to use the mouse wheel?'; Since you didn't know how you would be able to do it, I wanted to help you with a start point, and I did not intend to provide you with a complete solution. Again, the constant values are just for you to understand how this works.

Comment: Ok, I should have phrased that a little different then.