# Hide RichTextBox Scrollbars without losing Mouse Wheel scrolling

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to hide the `RichTextBox`'s Vertical and Horizontal scroll bars without losing the ability to scroll it using the mouse wheel... I have searched here and there without finding an effective solution for such problem ?

What i have tried so far

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.Style = cp.Style & ~0x200000; //Hides the scrollbars but doesn't allow mouse wheel scrolling...
        return cp;
    }
}
```

Comment: see the [c# - Hide scrollbars of a RichTextBox - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619471/hide-scrollbars-of-a-richtextbox)

Comment: @khan it's result is pretty bad (very weird scrolling you have to test it to see)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB.Net solution here [RichTextBox VScrollbar](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ba339154-95b7-4e13-a2c0-32593cadb984/richtextbox-vscrollbar?forum=vbgeneral)

You can create a custom control like below

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class RichTextBoxX : RichTextBox
{

    //// see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ba339154-95b7-4e13-a2c0-32593cadb984/richtextbox-vscrollbar?forum=vbgeneral
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    private uint WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;
    private const uint SB_LINEUP = 0;
    private const uint SB_LINEDOWN = 1;
    private const uint SB_PAGEUP = 2;
    private const uint SB_PAGEDOWN = 3;
    private const uint SB_TOP = 6;
    private const uint SB_BOTTOM = 7;

    private const uint SB_ENDSCROLL = 8;
    public RichTextBoxX()
    {
        this.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.None;
        this.MouseWheel += Me_MouseWheel;
    }


    private void Me_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Delta < 0)
            {
                // Scrolls down
                SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, (IntPtr)SB_LINEDOWN, IntPtr.Zero);
            }
            else
            {
                // Scrolls up
                SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, (IntPtr)SB_LINEUP, IntPtr.Zero);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

or without creating a custom control,

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    uint WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;
    private const uint SB_LINEUP = 0;
    private const uint SB_LINEDOWN = 1;
    private const uint SB_PAGEUP = 2;
    private const uint SB_PAGEDOWN = 3;
    private const uint SB_TOP = 6;
    private const uint SB_BOTTOM = 7;
    private const uint SB_ENDSCROLL = 8;


    void richTextBox1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Delta < 0)
        {
            SendMessage(richTextBox1.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, (IntPtr)SB_LINEDOWN, IntPtr.Zero);// Scrolls down
        }
        else
        {
            SendMessage(richTextBox1.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, (IntPtr)SB_LINEUP, IntPtr.Zero);// Scrolls up
        }
    }
```