# How to hide scroll bars without disabling them

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox, visual-c#-express-2010

Is there a way to scroll on a RichTextBox without the scroll bar visible?  I searched Google, but only came up with the `ScrollBars` Property.

I am using Microsoft Visual C# Express, winforms.

EDIT:
Something that would fix my problem would be a `void` with a few parameters such as a RTB, which direction to scroll, and how far to go.

Comment: did you look at this? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6b9c2c72-e91a-40f0-a835-c12328490c0c/how-to-scroll-without-a-scrollbar-or-make-scrollbar-invisible?forum=winforms

Comment: Or even this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1620221/3436942

Comment: You could set selected text and scroll to it, then remove/restore previous selection. See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.scrolltocaret.aspx).

Comment: @jbutler483 `RichTextBox` does not have a `VerticalScrollBar.Visible` Property.

Comment: You should be able to find some use to this, as well: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6914/Customize-a-panel-with-Autoscroll-property

Comment: @cullub you have the **scrollbar** property, though

Comment: @jbutler483 That just sets which scroll bars - not their visibility

Comment: @jbutler483 I thought of that, however if there are no scroll bars you can't scroll (it shouldn't be... :))

Comment: what happens if you use the mouse scroll effect in combination with them set to none?

Comment: @jbutler483 I suppose the mouse scroll event would work, only I would have to manually scroll the text rather than having .net do it for me, and I don't really want to go through that.

Comment: how were you 'wanting' to do it (without thinking how to, just whet you originally planned)?

Comment: @jbutler483 For example just set the actual scroll bar's visibility to false, while still being able to scroll.

Comment: like a drag and drop /iphone scrolling style?

Comment: @jbutler483 no - using like a mouse wheel.

Comment: did my second link not show you that?

Comment: @jbutler483 That applies to a panel.  I'll have to double-check, but I don't think it applies to a RichTextBox

Comment: We are talking about the second link, right> the one titled *"Hide scrollbars of a RichTextBox"*

Comment: @jbutler483 OOPS!! Sorry, I was looking at the third - I'll try #2, though.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61422/discussion-on-question-by-cullub-how-to-hide-scroll-bars-but-still-enable-them-c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some steps to do:

1. Put your RTB in a Panel (Dock: none)
2. Call panel.width -= 20; within your code.
3. Now we need a mouse wheel scrolling without focus, use my code below:

**Here is a little workaround:**

```
public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Works for panels, richtextboxes, 3rd party etc..
    Application.AddMessageFilter(new ScrollableControls(richTextBox1));
}
```

**ScrollableControls.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

//Let controls scroll without Focus();

namespace YOURNAMESPACE
{
    internal struct ScrollableControls : IMessageFilter
    {
        private const int WmMousewheel = 0x020A;
        private readonly Control[] _controls;

        public ScrollableControls(params Control[] controls)
        {
            _controls = controls;
        }

        bool IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg != WmMousewheel) return false;
            foreach (var item in _controls)
            {
                ScrollControl(item, ref m);
            }
            return false;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam);

        private static void ScrollControl(Control control, ref Message m)
        {
            if (control.RectangleToScreen(control.ClientRectangle).Contains(Cursor.Position) && control.Visible)
            {
                SendMessage(control.Handle, m.Msg, m.WParam.ToInt32(), m.LParam.ToInt32());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

4. **Keep** in mind that 3rd party controls often use nested container or similiar like radScrollablePanel1.PanelContainer, so you have to call them instead.

Comment: So how do I call this?  Do I put something in a handler?  Also, something that would fix my question, is a `void` with some parameters such as a rtb, that scrolls a certain distance up or down.  Can you do that?  Thanks!